# C# control flow

Tags: c#

I made a number which asks for 2 numbers with C# and responds with  the corresponding message for the case. how come it doesnt work  for the second number ? 
Regardless what I enter for the second number , I am getting the message "your number is in the range 0-10".

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string myInput;  // declaring the type of the variables
            int myInt;

            string number1;
            int number;


            Console.WriteLine("enter a number");
            myInput = Console.ReadLine(); //muyInput is a string  which is entry input
            myInt = Int32.Parse(myInput); // myInt converts the string into an Integer

            if (myInt > 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Your number {0} is greater than zero.", myInt);
            else if (myInt < 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Your number {0} is  less  than zero.", myInt);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Your number {0} is equal zero.", myInt);

            Console.WriteLine("enter another number");
            number1 = Console.ReadLine(); 
            number = Int32.Parse(myInput); 

            if (number < 0 || number == 0)
                Console.WriteLine("Your number {0} is  less  than zero or equal zero.", number);
            else if (number > 0 && number <= 10)
                Console.WriteLine("Your number {0} is  in the range from 0 to 10.", number);
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Your number {0} is greater than 10.", number);

            Console.WriteLine("enter another number");

        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 7):

`number = Int32.Parse(myInput);`  should read `number = Int32.Parse(number1);`

Answer (score 2):

```
number = Int32.Parse(myInput);
```

for the second number should be

```
number = Int32.Parse(number1);
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you are parsing the same string twice

```
number1 = Console.ReadLine(); 
number = Int32.Parse(myInput);
```

Should be

```
number1 = Console.ReadLine(); 
number = Int32.Parse(number1);
```

Comment: did somebody say "weltgeist" ? ;)

Answer (score 1):

What are you typing in as the first number? After "enter another number" you assign `number1` to the value from the console, but you never use that, you actually use the value from `myInput`

Answer (score 0):

```
number1 = Console.ReadLine(); 
number = Int32.Parse(myInput);
```

In your second test your evaluating the first input, it should be

```
Int32.Parse(number1);
```